# Apache and Django

Tags: python, django

Im trying to configure my Django site so that it is served by Apache.

**Folder Layout**

```
`-- django
    |
    `-- webtools
        |-- 1
        |-- __init__.py
        |-- __init__.pyc
        |-- apache
        |   `-- django.wsgi
        |-- macmonster
        |   |-- __init__.py
        |   |-- __init__.pyc
        |   |-- models.py
        |   |-- models.pyc
        |   |-- tests.py
        |   |-- views.py
        |   `-- views.pyc
        |-- manage.py
        |-- modules
        |   |-- __init__.py
        |   |-- __init__.pyc
        |   |-- macaddr.py
        |   |-- macaddr.pyc
        |   |-- validate.py
        |   `-- validate.pyc
        |-- settings.py
        |-- settings.pyc
        |-- urls.py
        `-- urls.pyc
```

**/etc/httpd/conf.d/django.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80 >
  ServerName direct.macmonster.co.uk
  WSGIScriptAlias / /opt/django/webtools/apache/django.wsgi
</VirtualHost>
```

**/opt/django/webtools/apache/django.wsgi**

```
import os, sys

sys.path.append('/opt/django/webtools')
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "settings")

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

The main error Im currently getting within the logs is :

**`TemplateSyntaxError: Caught ImportError while rendering: No module named webtools.macmonster`**

Thanks,

Comment: Seems to me like a PYTHONPATH problem. Is the appropriate directory on your PYTHONPATH? Does the Apache "user" have the correct permissions set on that directory?

Comment: Apache has read, execute permissions. As for the Pythonpath the appended sys.path should allow me to import modules from the webtools folder ? So Im a bit confused on what is wrong. Thanks

Comment: Ive just added both /opt/django/webtools and /opt/django to the sys.path things are now working. Though Im not sure why I need to add both of these?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If webtools is your top-level package, you should add `/opt/django` to the `sys.path`, not `/opt/django/webtools`.

Comment: If I add this to my sys.path I then get an issue with django not being able to find my views ?

Comment: Apparently you're importing things somewhat inconsistently. If you add `/opt/django` to the path, you can import `webtools` (and everything below it via `webtools`). If you add `/opt/django/webtools` to the path, you can import for example `macmonster` directly (whereas you would only be able to use `from webtools import macmonster` otherwise).

Comment: Ok thanks, what is the common practice for importing within Django. Is it just the project or the project.app ?

Answer (score 0):

This configuration works for me. This should work for you.

```
import os, sys

root = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'..')
sys.path.insert(0,root)
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "webtools.settings")

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```